# Tic Tac Toe Game on Python using TURTLE

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I would like to make a Tic Tac Toe using turtle on python.

Assuming that I make a grid by making 9 squares using the following code:

```
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.left(90)
```

Is it possible to be able to click on one of those squares and have the position return or saved? 
Is it possible to make a Tic Tac Toe game on python using turtle? I know thata  Tic Tac Toe code can be made by using python but can you make a code using turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that prints the coordinates of the click

```
def onclick(x, y):
    print x, y

turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(onclick)
```

You'll need to do some transformation - translate and divide by 60 etc. to work out which square has been clicked.

Comment: No worries. I originally thought this was a bit silly and you should just use TK widgets, but now I'm thinking it's not a bad way to start learning about callbacks